# UITableView has a gap above the first cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

There's a white gap above the first cell of my table view that disappears when you interact with the view in any way. The gap is as high as the navigation bar. I already tried `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` and using a 0 by 0 view as the header. The first method does nothing and the second one produces glitched results.

Answer (score 0):

Apply

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

and

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
```

as you said. This works for me.

Ah, one more thing. **Important**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return HEIGHT_DEFAULT_TABLE_HEADER;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return HEIGHT_DEFAULT_TABLE_FOOTER;
}
```

These two methods can adjust height of header and footer for the table view.

Comment: I don't want the navigation bar to be hidden so that wouldn't help. And I know how to change the header and footer heights, but the gap doesn't seem to have to do with those.

Comment: FYI - the question is tagged Swift, not Objective-C.

Comment: Ok it's swift.., @Pixel BTW did you add it in viewDidLoad or somewhere? In my case I added it in viewDidLoad

Comment: @HwanghoKim the linked answer helped. Thank you. I had to also set automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets on the parent view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried every possible solution and found it for iOS 11 and above use:

```
    self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me at one point. Try product -> clean project.

Also try restarting XCode.

If that doesn't work, try removing the header entirely. Why have a header at all if you are going to set its values to 0 by 0.

Also make sure the insets on the attributes inspector are also zero.

If none of these work, try the solution with the most work, which is to delete your `UITableView` entirely and adding it again :(

Comment: Tried all of those things, nothing helped.